# Calculating square meter area with polygonal geographical coordinates (metric - not DMS system)

Tags: coordinate-systems, area, polygons

I'm working on a program but my problem is not on software side but mathematical.

I have the following input :

```
{
   "type":"Feature",
   "id":"64100000BA0033",
   "geometry":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[
         [
            [
               -1.4796836,
               43.4414704
            ],
            [
               -1.4796624,
               43.441522
            ],
            [
               -1.4797672,
               43.4415449
            ],
            [
               -1.4797607,
               43.4415605
            ],
            [
               -1.47976,
               43.4415624
            ],
            [
               -1.4798095,
               43.4415732
            ],
            [
               -1.479838,
               43.4415041
            ],
            [
               -1.4796836,
               43.4414704
            ]
         ]
      ]
   },
   "properties":{
      "id":"64100000BA0033",
      "commune":"64100",
      "prefixe":"000",
      "section":"BA",
      "numero":"33",
      "contenance":87,
      "created":"2004-10-14",
      "updated":"2018-01-19"
   }
}
```

This input is, as you can imagine, variable (nbr of points) for every land available in my region. I'd need to know what is the formula to get the area in m² (square meters) from these coordinates.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks !

Comment: What are the units for these coordinates? Without this, no conversion is possible.

Comment: It's decimal degrees

Comment: Note that if those are latitude and longitude degrees, then they are equal only at the equator. That is, a degree of longitude relative to degree of latitude needs a factor of cosine of latitude.

Comment: I know. But I don't know the formula unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The formula/algorithm you are looking for can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Some comments for your application:

1) To apply the formula you need to be sure that the order the points are given corresponds to the order they form the outer border of the area you want to measure.

2) Your input data does not to mention units, so you have to make sure to get the conversion right. From the data it looks like the unit is something much bigger than m, maybe km or miles or something else (maybe some angles from a spherical coordinate system; make sure you completely understand what those numbers mean).

3) Make sure to use enough precision in the numerics, as the values are all very much the same and once you start subtracting them your remaining precision will go down much.

Comment: 4) The shoelace formula is only valid in a plane, make sure the approximation is not too coarse when applied to a spherical surface (ok if the region is small).

Comment: Yes, the points are sorted. The unit is Decimal Degrees. Since I'll only apply this to small areas (500 - 5000 m²) I can use a plane surface formula. Maybe getting the average between 2 points, get the length of 1 degree at this average point, multiply thids length by the distance in deg (0.00???) of these two points and I'll have something accurate enough with the shoelace formula, right ?

Comment: Yes, at those close ranges anything like this will produce something that is accurate enough.